# How to find out if a video file has picture types P and/or B and uses inter-frame prediction optimally?

Tags: compression

Over on Super User, I asked the question, ["What file properties affect the size of a video file?"](https://superuser.com/questions/1830199/what-file-properties-affect-the-size-of-a-video-file). A comment from Gantendo taught me about [picture types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types) and the apparently equivalent [frame types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_frame). Another comment from him taught me that I can inspect a file to observe the use of these techniques by installing [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) and running:

```
FFmpeg -i <filespec> -vf "showinfo" -f null -
```

and then looking at the values of the field `type` in the output.

I did that on one of my files and if I understand the output, it has some introductory data followed by a line of data for every frame, including a field `type`. From a quick look at that output, it appears that there are a few I frames, while most of the frames are of type P. So it seems that the file is using "[inter-frame prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_frame)" a lot.

My question has four parts:

- Is there a way to tell if a file is using inter-frame prediction without having to inspect thousands of lines of output from FFmpeg?
- Is there a way to tell if a file is using inter-frame prediction optimally, so that I know whether this type of compression is being done as well as possible or could be improved?
- If a file is not using inter-frame prediction, is there a way to convert it to one that does?
- If a file is using inter-frame prediction, but not optimally, is there a way to convert it to a file that uses the technique better?

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to learn how videocompression works in detail? It is a bunch of math and I know only the very basics? Do you have a specific file or set of files you want to compress as much as possible? https://imagekit.io/blog/video-compression-techniques/

Comment: I doubt this is the best place to ask these questions, I think people here are usually more interested in actually producing video than the intricacies of compression.

Comment: `Is there a way to tell if a file is using inter-frame prediction` Yes, you can look at which codec is used. If it is a codec that does not use inter-frame prediction then it is not used and vice versa

Comment: `Is there a way to tell if a file is using inter-frame prediction optimally` "Optimal" is a difficult word in this context because, since there is a tradeoff between space (and even gpu/cpu used) and quality. Use H.265 and it is pretty damn good.

Comment: `If a file is not using inter-frame prediction, is there a way to convert it to one that does?` Yes, you can convert videos from one codec to another. You should check out Handbrake.

Comment: `If a file is using inter-frame prediction, but not optimally, is there a way to convert it to a file that uses the technique better?` If a file is  H.264 you can convert it to H.265 which should improve compression. https://www.boxcast.com/blog/hevc-h.265-vs.-h.264-avc-whats-the-difference

Comment: Inter-frame and intra-frame compression are just two techniques that are used in video compression. It gets pretty boring when you start learning about spatial and temporal redundancy, quantization, entropy coding and motion compensation and the math required to do all that.

Comment: @Gantendo - Thank you. You answered all four parts of my question. Is there a reason you don't want to post that as an answer? If you do, I would like to accept it.

Comment: I don't really believe in reputation points so I basically always use comments. Its also laziness because people want you to format answers beautifully. In a comment I can just post a link but if I post a link as an answer people demand that I take the info from that link and put it in the answer which is often a lot more work and doesn't really benefit the OP.

Comment: I am here to help people, not to boost my already sizable ego with fake points https://home.tdarr.io/ is pretty dope too

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is compiled from comments on the question made by Gantendo.

A helpful resource for understanding video compression is [*A Detailed Overview Of Popular Video Compression Techniques*](https://imagekit.io/blog/video-compression-techniques/) by ImageKit.

- Is there a way to tell if a file is using inter-frame prediction?

  - Yes, you can look at which codec is used. If it is a codec that does not use inter-frame prediction then it is not used and vice versa.

    - (This part of the answer is not entirely helpful. How can I know if a particular codec uses it? I have not found a place with this information.)
- Is there a way to tell if a file is using inter-frame prediction optimally?

  - "Optimal" is a difficult word in this context because, since there is a tradeoff between space (and even gpu/cpu used) and quality. Use H.265 and it is pretty damn good.
- If a file is not using inter-frame prediction, is there a way to convert it to one that does?

  - Yes, you can convert videos from one codec to another. Check out [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/1.7.0/introduction/about.html) and [Tdarr](https://docs.tdarr.io/docs/welcome/what).

    - In addition to those, it appears that [ImageKit](https://imagekit.io) also does this. The [ImageKit article](https://imagekit.io/blog/video-compression-techniques/) also says VLC and Adobe Media Encoder can be used.
- If a file is using inter-frame prediction, but not optimally, is there a way to convert it to a file that uses the technique better?

  - If a file is H.264 you can convert it to H.265 which should improve compression. See [*HEVC (H.265) vs. AVC (H.264): What’s the Difference?*](https://www.boxcast.com/blog/hevc-h.265-vs.-h.264-avc-whats-the-difference) by BoxCast.

Comment: That ImageKit link says: "Examples of intra-frame codecs are MJPEG, ProRes, and DNxHD, while examples of inter-frame codecs are H.264, H.265, and VP9."